# How to implement Secure Content Delivery in SDL Tridion 2013?

Tags: content-delivery, 2013

I need to implement secure content delivery in Tridion 2013 for providing the security to the content based on the roles, but I gone through the document on SDLTridionWorld (https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/securecontentdeliveryoverviewfaq.aspx) site and get to know that 
The Secure Content Delivery module is only available for the following Tridion Releases:

Tridion R5.1 SP2
Tridion R5.1 SP3
Tridion R5.1 SP4

So if that is the case then how i can do implementation in Tridion 2013 version.

Comment: From where I can get the documentation or help for the Secure Content Delivery for Trdion 2013

Answer (score 5):

That document is out of date. I am pretty sure there is a version compatible with 2013. If you have a license for it, then you can contact Customer Support to get it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using asp.net delivery, one approach would be to add an "Roles" attribute on relevant schemas, output these information in a TBB to the sitemap file, and customise your SiteMapProvider to respect these roles (with security trimming enabled, which integrates with .NET Role Provider). This is useful for menus, breadcrumbs and other navigation.

When a page is being requested, you could then implement a RoleProvider to basically check if the current user is in a role, and if it is, allow the access to a page based on the SiteMapProvider information.

[See this link about Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

If you want to protect on a component level, when requesting a page, you could create a custom security enabled ComponentPresentation control. Then another TBB would replace the default tridion:ComponentPresentation to your customer one.

This all depends on your detailed requirement but this link on [SiteMapProvider Security Trimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.ASPX) could be useful.